# change the visibility of elements after each time click the button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have set of XAML elements like below:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comB1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed">
<ComboBox x:Name="comB2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed">
<ComboBox x:Name="comB3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,270,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed">


<Button Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="51" Width="59" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

I want to change the `Visibility` of one `ComboBox` to `visible` after each time I click this `+` button.

Comment: You want to change the visibility of the same combobox every time, or show a different one?

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean to make one visible, but hide the previous ones, or successively make each one visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution works for any count of `ComboBoxes`. Try this:

```
int num = 1;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (num <= ComboCounts)//ComboCounts is count of your ComboBoxes
    {
        ((ComboBox)this.FindName("comB" + num)).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        num++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int ComboNO = 0;
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     ComboNO++;
     for (int i = 0; i < ComboCount; i++)
        if (ComboNO == i)
          foreach (FrameworkElement item in RootElement.Children)
             if (item.Name == "comB" + i) item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Hey what is this 'RootElement'

Comment: @Mr.lock - It should be whatever element contains your comboboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick:

-- declare a variable in the scope of class

```
int numOfVisibleCbx = 0;
```

-- on button click

```
if(numOfVisibleCbx == 0)
      comB1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
else if(numOfVisibleCbx == 1)
      comB2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
else if(numOfVisibleCbx == 2)
      comB3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

numOfVisibleCbx++;
```

Comment: Ya It's good.But if there are 30 combo-boxes Then I have to write 60-70 lines.Is there any possible answers

Comment: @Mr.lock - You need to include this detail in your question.

Comment: of course, if there are many combobox then it would be a problem but where is a problem then there is a solution as well.

what we can do is to take a wrap panel and add comboboxes dynamically in it on "+" click.

also, you can store the referance of those comboboxes in a list so that if you need to manipulate them then it could be done easily

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to hide other cbx then

Here is a trick:

-- declare a variable in the scope of class

```
int numOfVisibleCbx = 0;
```

-- function

```
void hideAll()
{
     comB1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     comB2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     comB3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

-- on button click

```
hideAll();
if(numOfVisibleCbx == 0)
      comB1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
else if(numOfVisibleCbx == 1)
      comB2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
else if(numOfVisibleCbx == 2){
      comB3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
      numOfVisibleCbx = 0;
}
numOfVisibleCbx++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _comBs =
            this
                .Root
                .Children
                .OfType<ComboBox>()
                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comB"))
                .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Name.Substring("comB".Length)))
                .ToArray();
    }

    private ComboBox[] _comBs = null;
    private int _comB_index = -1;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _comB_index++;
        for (var i = 0; i < _comBs.Length; i++)
        {
            _comBs[i].Visibility = i == _comB_index % _comBs.Length
                ? Visibility.Visible
                : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

You would have to replace `this.Root` with your container element.

I have tested this solution and it works.